# arrow button - based on codrops "awesome slide out button"

Tags: jquery, button

I'm trying to make two arrow buttons to the left and to the right, based on codrops - [awesome slide out button](http://www.tympanus.net/Tutorials/SlideOutButton/).

It's ok with the right arrow, i.e., when hover to the arrow the info (RIGHT) slides to the right. But i could not do that with the left side, i.e., when hover the info (LEFT) don't slide to the left. ([Here](http://www.tiyatrostudyosu.com/button/index.html) is what i mean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
.button_aLeft {
     left: 0px;
}
```

to this:

```
.button_aLeft {
     right: 0;
}
```

in line 12 of your CSS